# How to put a gray box around text that splits at page break

Tags: tcolorbox, backgrounds, colorbox

Is there a way to create a gray box around text that will split upon a page break? For example, using `tcolorbox` I can get the following:

[image]

However, it will shift onto the next page if it does not fit on the current page, and if it does not fit on a single page, it will run past the end of the page. I also do not want to manually do it because changing the content on previous pages would mess up the exact lining.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tcolorbox` provides library `breakable` for automatically breaking boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,boxrule=0pt]
  \lipsum
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: two pages of document with box across two pages]

See [section 19 of the user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf#section.19) for more information about `breakable`.

There are alternatives like `mdframed` or `framed` which provide similar feature for boxes with background across pages.

Comment: When I used breakable, the border where it breaks has very weird behavior, regardless of the tool I am using to view the pdf. At certain zoom levels, I will see a solid border, and at other levels I do not see it. I thought this might just be a result of pixel use, but it doesn't happen for other borders. Upon extreme zoom, I can see the slightest color change at the border. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @MikeSmith If you have a new question, please ask a new question. Currently I do not understand, whether you are talking about a viewer issue or problems in setting the color and width of a border or shadown.